# Python pandas dataframe "Don't want to trim values"

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

When making a data frame that contains person location coordinates as latitude and longitude (eg, lat: 51.7122369865437 and long: 9.24231274054315) the panda's data frame is trimming the value of latitude and both longitude. How to stop it and store original coordinates.

Comment: It probably isn't, that's just how floats are being represented.

Comment: Use `pd.set_option('precision',14)` to check out if it is trimmed or not

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you're seeing isn't a precision issue... it's more a display issue. Take a look at the level of precision that pandas currently offers, as you may need to increase it -

```
pd.options.display.precision
6 

df = pd.DataFrame({'latitude' : [51.7122369865437], 'longitude' : [9.24231274054315]})    
df

    latitude  longitude
0  51.712237   9.242313
```

You can see (on my system) that the level of precision is `6`, meaning only the first 6 decimals are displayed. If you need a greater degree of precision, you can just set it -

```
pd.options.display.precision = 15
```

Or,

```
pd.set_options('display.precision', 15)
```

And now, print `df` again -

```
df

             latitude         longitude
0  51.712236986543701  9.24231274054315
```

Comment: @jlandercy Cheers, I was typing up a solution while you posted :-)